# how to show checkbox on image mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using a BlueImp Gallery to add lightboxes to my image gallery. So, I want to show a checkbox on mouseover on the topleft corner of the image and when I select checkbox it should show always on the image.

```
<div id="links">
    @foreach (var images in Model)
    {
        <a href="@Url.Content("~/ImageGallery/" + images.Imgs)" data-gallery>
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/ImageGallery/thumbnails/" + images.Imgs)">
        </a>
        @Html.CheckBox("delete_CheckBox", false, new { Value = images.Imgs })
    }

</div>
```

Now it is showing like this and checkboxes are showing always (red circle). I want show checkboxes only when mouseover on the topleft corner of the image (black squarebox) and on selection checkbox should show always.

How can I do with css or jquery?

### Generated HTML

```
     <div id="links">
        <a href="/ImageGallery/11.jpg" data-gallery>
           <img src="/ImageGallery/thumbnails/11.jpg">
        </a>
        <input Value="11.jpg" id="delete_CheckBox" name="delete_CheckBox" type="checkbox" 
         value="true" />
         <input name="delete_CheckBox" type="hidden" value="false" />  

         <a href="/ImageGallery/Chrysanthemum.jpg" data-gallery>
            <img src="/ImageGallery/thumbnails/Chrysanthemum.jpg">
         </a>
        <input Value="Chrysanthemum.jpg" id="delete_CheckBox" name="delete_CheckBox" 
        type="checkbox" value="true" />
        <input name="delete_CheckBox" type="hidden" value="false" />  

        <a href="/ImageGallery/Desert.jpg" data-gallery>
           <img src="/ImageGallery/thumbnails/Desert.jpg">
        </a>
        <input Value="Desert.jpg" id="delete_CheckBox" name="delete_CheckBox" 
        type="checkbox" value="true" />
        <input name="delete_CheckBox" type="hidden" value="false" />                

        <a href="/ImageGallery/google.png" data-gallery>
           <img src="/ImageGallery/thumbnails/google.png">
        </a>
        <input Value="google.png" id="delete_CheckBox" name="delete_CheckBox" 
        type="checkbox" value="true" />
        <input name="delete_CheckBox" type="hidden" value="false" />                

        <a href="/ImageGallery/Hydrangeas.jpg" data-gallery>
           <img src="/ImageGallery/thumbnails/Hydrangeas.jpg">
        </a>
        <input Value="Hydrangeas.jpg" id="delete_CheckBox" name="delete_CheckBox" 
        type="checkbox" value="true" />
        <input name="delete_CheckBox" type="hidden" value="false" />                

        <a href="/ImageGallery/Jellyfish.jpg" data-gallery>
           <img src="/ImageGallery/thumbnails/Jellyfish.jpg">
        </a>
        <input Value="Jellyfish.jpg" id="delete_CheckBox" name="delete_CheckBox" 
        type="checkbox" value="true" />
        <input name="delete_CheckBox" type="hidden" value="false" />                

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you tied to that HTML, or are you able to restructure a little?

Comment: may be this will help?

Comment: This seems like mostly a CSS issue as it has to do with positioning of the checkbox. Do you have access to all the CSS attributes for the page?

Answer (score 1):

To position the checkbox, I usually just add a div around the whole thing (right inside your foreach) with relative position, and put the checkbox in there with absolute position. In your case you want to do 4px from top and left.

To hide the checkbox, you could set the checkbox's css to hidden by default, and to show on :checked selector.

The hover is the trickiest to do. Instead of setting the checkbox's css to hidden, set opacity to 0. Then use the :hover selector to set opacity to 1.

That's it. If you need exactly code samples or clarifications I could add some more here.

Comment: Please take the time to add code examples to your answer, in order to illustrate your intent and to make the answer an answer, rather than a *description of* an answer. In this instance I put together this approach (which is basically the same as you described in your answer), that you may as well have for illustration: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WF5n5/1/), though this makes the assumption that the wrapping has been effected server-side, and I use `<span>` elements, rather than `<div>`.

Comment: Nice :) Thanks David! Didn't have time, was in the middle of something else but still wanted to help a bit :)

Comment: No problem, but you'll find you get more upvotes/imaginary-internet-points if you provide demos that the OP can use and learn from; as well as those others coming across the question in future.

Comment: @DavidThomas, thanks for your help. your JS Fiddle helps. Please Answer my question so I can mark answer.